# i need to write a java string of Special Character and numbers from 0 to 9 to validate a password

Tags: java, validation, passwords

i need to write a java string of  Special Character and numbers from 0 to 9 to validate a password, so i created a method that receives String and return string as shown below ,,,,
but i cant write a string for all Special Characters and another one for the numbers from 0 to 9

```
public String isPasswordvalid(String password) {

    String x = password;
    String specialChars = "(.*[,~,!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,(,),-,_,=,+,[,{,],},|,;,:,<,>,/,?].*$)";
    String passwordNumbers = "(.*[0-9].*)";
    String minSixCharacterErrorMessage = "Invalid password,Password should be at least 6 character ";
    String emptyFieldErrorMessage = "Invalid password,Field is empty , please enter a Valid password";
    String missingSpecialCharacterErrorMessage = "Invalid password, It must contains a special charctar";
    String numberErrorMessage = "Invalid password, It must contains at least one number";
    String noSpaceCharacterErrorMessage = "Invalid password, Password cant contains spaces";

    if (x.isEmpty()) {
        // System.out.println("Field is empty , please enter a Valid password");
        return emptyFieldErrorMessage;


    } else if (x.length() < 6) {
        // System.out.println("Password should be min 6 character ");
        return minSixCharacterErrorMessage;

    } else if (!x.contains(specialChars)) {
        //System.out.println("Invalid password, It must contains a special charctar");
        return missingSpecialCharacterErrorMessage;

    } else if (!x.contains(passwordNumbers)) {
        //System.out.println("Invalid password, It must contains at least one number");
        return numberErrorMessage;

    } else if (x.contains(" ")) {
        //System.out.println("Invalid password, Password cant contains spaces");
        return noSpaceCharacterErrorMessage;


    }

    return "";


}
```

Comment: Are you just looking to add a certain list of allowable characters?

Comment: `contains` doesn't use regex. You may want to look at `matches` instead.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: thanks alot ,,, i could kiss u

Comment: i thought  the problem was the string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains-java.lang.CharSequence-) doesn't use regex. You may want to look at [`matches`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches-java.lang.String-) instead. Check also the linked javadoc for reference.